# Directory hidden in visual studio code explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem that has been bugging me for months. I have a software directory structure which when viewed in visual studio code explorer is missing a directory called 'install' all other directories are visible. If I delete the 'install' directory and recreate it with visual studio code explorer (right click and select new folder) it does not appear in the explorer but does appear in the file system.

Somehow visual studio explorer seems to be filtering out any directory call 'install' anywhere in the directory structure or on any other filesystem.

The same thing happens if I try and create an 'install' directory on any filesystem, local filesystem, local git repo, remote folder, etc.

Any suggestions about how this is happening and what to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have by accident a setting like this in your settings.json file:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "install": true
},
```

If you use the gui for your settings instead of the json file, search for "Files: Exclude" and you will see the files or folders that are told not to display.